# Retrieving only metadata information from object stored in s3 without reading the object payload

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am storing object which consists of stream and metadata in s3 using aws java sdk v2.

Metadata is a map of values extracted from object received from UI.
My code looks this

```
response=s3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).metadata(metadata(media)).build(),
                        RequestBody.fromBytes(readAsBytesFromStream(media)));
```

I want to retrieve only the meta information from the object saved and not read the object's payload.

The use case is i have to read only the meta info to render on UI preventing s3 to read object's content.
Is there any way where i can read only the meta info and not the content of saved object.As reading multiple object's content(payload+metadata) and then rendering would make it slow.
Some other way to store meta and payload separately so that reading meta becomes efficient .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `headObject` method.

Something like:

```
response = s3Client.headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build();
metadata = response.metadata();
```

SDK documentation:

- https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#headObject-java.util.function.Consumer-
- https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/HeadObjectResponse.html

Comment: Should be s3Client.headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder() ...